# access rails image_tag helper in liquid drop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, liquid

Does anyone know how to access the image_tag rails helper from within a liquid drop ?

Any help / examples would be great as i can't seem to find this anywhere!

thanks 
rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the Liquid Template engine right?

If so, by design, the `image_tag` helper is entirely unavailable from within Liquid templates. This is the express purpose of Liquid, you aren't able to execute any Ruby code on the server running Liquid, just the set of helpers that it provides you.

If you are making a Shopify store or something like this where you are using Liquid on someone else's servers, then you are stuck manually doing what the `image` tag helper does normally. You have to write out `<img src="{{ something.url }}>`.

If you are making or running your own Rails application which uses Liquid, you can add your own `image_tag` style filter to Liquid so that its available for use in all your templates. 
See [Liquid for Programmers](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Programmers) on the Github wiki.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i am using it in my own rails app and can create image_tag method but surely thats just duplicating the code ??   surely you can pull them in to use

Comment: @rick There's no one liner to import all your Rails helpers if thats what you are looking for. If you are using Liquid to execute user supplied templates, then I would try to provide as few helpers as possible and rather just let users write `<img src..` and so on, instead of letting them execute Ruby code on your servers. If you are using Liquid to write your own templates for your site, I would suggest perhaps choosing a different template language if you miss those helpers. Liquid is purposefully designed to have a limited set of super secure helpers, which I guess excludes image_tag. HTH!

Comment: The [Liquid `img_tag` filter](http://wiki.shopify.com/Img_tag) or [this image tag plugin](https://gist.github.com/1548864) might be useful.